# Stored Procedure results different in SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure in my code and the results are being loaded into a DataTable, here is a column from the Datatable.

[image: Code Results Column]

However, the time portion of the date is not supposed to be there. In the stored procedure, I am doing this: "Cast(loan.OpenedDate as date) as OpenedDate". In SQL if I execute this stored procedure, it displays correctly as shown here.

[image: SQL Results Column]

Why would the results differ if the procedure is the same?

Comment: because c# doesnt have a date only type, so its added times to it

Comment: The results are exactly the same in both tables.  A DateTime object when no hour, minutes, and seconds are used defaults to midnight at the beginning of the day.  You are just displaying the same dates with and without the hours, minutes, seconds.

Comment: Saying these results are different is like looking at a car from 2 different angles and claiming they're different cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Because in Code it has DataType of **DateTime** because C# Doesn't have **Date** DataType

So what you do is Use [DateTime.ToShortDateString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx)
Method

E.g

```
DateTime dateToDisplay = new DateTime(2009, 6, 1, 8, 42, 50);
dateToDisplay.ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no Date type in C#, only DateTime, so your SQL Date result is being converted to a DateTime.